# Convert XML element node to child node

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to know how you could change the level of an XML node in PowerShell.

For example, from this:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>One</child>
        <child>Two</child>
        <child>Three</child>
        <child>Four</child>
        <child>Five</child>
        <child>six</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

to this:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>Two</grandchild>
            <grandchild>Three</grandchild>
            <grandchild>Four</grandchild>
            <grandchild>Five</grandchild>
            <grandchild>six</grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

---

Also, off-topic, but does the commandlet `Out-Null` ONLY ignore the output? It seems to be ignoring my script result, too. I'm creating and writing into a file and when I try to open the file, I'm told that it does not exist. However, when I don't ignore the output, it successfully creates and writes the file but takes much longer.

Comment: Ehhh... You seem to have placed that `child` closing tag a little early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new (empty) `<child>` node.
2. Create new `<grandchild>` nodes with the content of the `<child>` nodes.
3. Append the `<grandchild>` nodes to the new `<child>` node.
4. Remove the existing `<child>` nodes.
5. Append the `<child>` node to the `<parent>` node.

Sample code:

```
[xml]$xml = '<root>...</root>'

$child = $xml.CreateElement('child')

$xml.SelectNodes('//child') | % {
  $n = $xml.CreateElement('grandchild')
  $n.InnerText = $_.InnerText
  $child.AppendChild($n)

  [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}

$xml.SelectNodes('//parent').AppendChild($child)
```

As for [`Out-Null`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx): the cmdlet discards all output on the [success output stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx).